# How to toggle bold on/off for a UILabel IBOutlet?

Tags: ios

I want to be able to toggle the bold on/off for a UILabel, all previous questions in this area use UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:.

But as the UILabel is an IBOutlet the font size is already set in the xib, is there no way of setting the boldness independently from the from size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `UILabel`'s `font` property to be a bold font programatically whenever you want, assuming you have it connected to an IBOutlet like you said.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see a bold property or method on UIFont. Only boldSystemFontOfSize: - so it seems you have to set the size at the same time as the boldness. My question is can you set the bold independently of setting the size, if so how? I don't see anything in the documentation for UIFont. Also if the text is already bold, how to turn it off?

Comment: well actually, if you already set the font size in the XIB, it will get reset to whatever size you specify the `UIFont` via `boldSystemFontOfSize`.

Comment: So there is no way to just set the boldness on its own. How do you find out the current font size so you can keep it the same when using boldSystemFontOfSize to set the boldness? PointSize?

Comment: Sure!  get the current `UIFont` from the label, then get the current size from that font via it's `pointSize` property... then create the new bold font passing in the original font's `pointSize` property, and assign the bold font to your label.  How is that?

Comment: Its ridiculous. Not your answer, the convoluted process to set one simple attribute. That's why I was asking to make sure I wasn't missing something in the documentation as I was expecting a nice simple SetBold etc.

Comment: It might seem convoluted, but it does give developers a lot of useful flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Bold fonts are actually different fonts than non-bold. Take a look at this in the simulator and you'll see all the possible iOS fonts, including bold variations:

https://github.com/akosma/fontbrowser

[image: Some fonts from akosma's browser]

Alternatively, check this website: http://iosfonts.com/

To set the font to bold for say, Helvetica, you could do something like:

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:myLabel.font.pointSize];
```

(apologies for any typos, I am typing from memory not in Xcode).

Then to switch back, reverse:

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:myLabel.font.pointSize];
```

This is generic in that you aren't forcing the point size in your code, just maintaining it as you switch back and forth.

Enjoy,

Damien